QField can not open project on iOS
I run QField (vers. 3.2.2) on iOS (vers. 17.5.1, iPhone11). I packed my QGIS project with the help of the QfieldSync extension (vers. 4.9.1) and transferred it to the iPhone internatal storage via One Drive, copying it to the QField folder.
When I try to open the qgs-file I got the following error log:

Project file read error in file
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CA18B5FF-350D-426C-867E-559E4874659C/Documents/Imported
Datasets/QField/QField/fbf_qField_qfield.qgs: Start tag expected. at
line 1 column 1
Error opening zip archive:
'/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CA18B5FF-350D-426C-867E-559E4874659C/Documents/Imported
Datasets/QField/QField/fbf_qField_qfield_attachments.zip' (Error code:
19)


You should copy/move your project folder from One Drive to /On My iPhone/QField/Imported Projects.
Then you can open the project from QField App...
Regards (:

Thanks and sorry for delayed feedback. By doing this, I still get the same error "unable to unzip file"
